# PyQt5 QFileDialog closes when filename clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I am using `PyQt5 QFileDialog.getOpenFileName`.  I am expecting the box to remain open until the "open" button is clicked.  However, when I run the code on my Linux system, the dialog box closes immediately when the file name is clicked.  On a Windows system, the box behaves as expected and remains open until the 'Open' button is clicked.  The results are the same with or without the `QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog` option set.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileDialog

import sys


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("QFileDialog Test")

        button = QPushButton("Click to open file")
        button.setCheckable(True)
        button.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        # Set the central widget of the Window.
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def open_file(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File",
            "", "Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)",options=options)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Main()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Edit:
I logged out of KDE and started an Openbox session instead, then ran the above code.  QFileDialog behaved as I was expecting, and waited for me to click the Open button.  This verifies the problem exists with KDE / KWin, and that the code, run under other window managers, will likely work fine.

Still isn't a real solution, but I am more informed now than I was earlier.

2nd Edit:
I found that if I change Workspace Behavior -> General Behavior -> Click Behavior from Single click, to Double click, my QFileDialog issue goes away. How to get around this would be a different topic though.

3rd Edit:
Added 'QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog' option to sample code.

Comment: Your code runs as expected on artix linux, python 3.8.5, pyqt 5.15

Comment: What is your window manager: gnome, kde, etc?

Comment: This system is KDE Plasma on Fedora 32 with Python 3.8.5 and pyqt 5.15.  Encouraging  to hear that it runs OK on a different linux system.  I'm still in the dark as to why its behaving like this on my system and what to do about it.  But at least I know now that the scope is a bit more narrow.

Comment: i tried it successfully on i3, openbox, xfce, gnome-wayland

Comment: @a_manthey_67 - Thanks for the info.  Looks like it works everywhere but KDE.

Comment: Are you sure you're correctly applying the `DontUseNativeDialog` option? I don't see it in your example, and it should work (since it overrides the native dialog, it should *not* use the underlying desktop behavior). Can you update your code to include that also?

Comment: Hello - @musicamante - No, actually I'm __not__ sure I'm applying the DontUseNativeDialog option correctly.  I looked for additional flags that needed to be set, but found none.  I have updated my sample code with what I have tried.  What did I miss?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Qt tries to respect the way the OS opens files and folders in its file manager, even when using the native dialog. That depends on the `SH_ItemView_ActivateItemOnSingleClick` [style hint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#styleHint), and the only way to bypass it is to apply a proxy style.

While you could apply the style to the QFileDialog's view within its `__init__` (as long as you're using the native dialog), you're using static methods, so you can only do this by setting the style to the whole QApplication.

Note that, unlike stylesheets, palette and font, styles are not propagated to children widgets, and they *always* use the QApplication style (or the style manually set for them).

```
class SingleClickWorkaroundProxy(QProxyStyle):
    def styleHint(self, hint, option, widget, data):
        if hint == self.SH_ItemView_ActivateItemOnSingleClick:
            return False
        return super().styleHint(hint, option, widget, data)

# ...
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(SingleClickWorkaroundProxy())
window = Main()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hello again @musicamante.  Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you very much.  I never would have solved this one.